# how do you save the output of a function that prints in C language?

Tags: c, file-io

let's say there is a (void)function I define that prints some numbers and I want to check if it prints the correct content. I'm thinking writing the content to a file and read it back and check if it is what I wanted.  But I dont know how since the function is void and returns nothing.

Comment: Environment? Shell? Language? Fix tags and expand the question please.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using my phone and for some reason I can't put file I/O as one tag .

Comment: That looks good now :)

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't really clear because I was using my phone. I was trying to find out how I can write data that is printed to stdout in to a file and I found freopen() which does the job :). Thanks for the help tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out I can use freopen() to write data into a file from stdout. My bad for not making the question more clear.